# Formula to Get data for a specific date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Date        Time            Country         Desc
16/04/14    8.30 am         India           abcd
16/04/14    9.30 am         India           pqrs
17/04/14    9.30 am         India           xyz
17/04/14    10.30 am        India           abcd
```

I wish to get all the data of 16/04/14 in another sheet using formula. Vlookup takes only the first row data as reference is 16/04/14. Is there any other way to get data.

Comment: How do you wish to return the data? For example, `16/04/14` have 2 values. Do you want to return it like you're filtering it, still in table format?

Comment: Yes. I want the data of entire row corresponding to 16/04/14, just like filtering of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this then:

Assuming you have this data in `Sheet1`:

[image]

And you want to get all matches of dates in `Sheet2` like this:

[image]

What you need to do is use this formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$5,SMALL((IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW(Sheet1!A$1:A$5))),ROW($A1)),1),"")`
Above is an `Array Formula` entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Enter it in `A2` then copy on the remaining cells.
For our example, I copied it until `Row 10 (A2:D10)`.
Then you just need to type in the value you want displayed in `E1` as shown in the picture.
Then all the columns will populate with the data that you need.
Hope this helps.

**Important:** The ranges in the formula needs to be adjusted to suit your needs.